# vuepress router-link active styling not working

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I have a basicNotation.md file, which routes fine.

```
<router-link to="/basicNotation">Test</router-link>
```

However when this is rendered, and i route to it, this is the result:

```
<a href="/basicNotation" class="">Test</a>
```

**Note how there is no class applied to the anchor tag!**

*The render should look like this, according to the vuejs docs:
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class*

```
<a href="/basicNotation" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">Test</a>
```

**Where am I going wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I added the file extension to the path:

```
<router-link to="/basicNotation.html">Test</router-link>
```

And it works, as far as I can tell. Renders to this:

```
<a href="/basicNotation.html" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">Test</a>
```

I'm still open to better solutions.

Comment: Of course, if you use clean URLs (esp. the vuepress clean url plugin or server configs), you would set the to property accordingly to the cleaned URL.